# chrome extention : I want capture the selected tab screen when user clicks a link

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to capture the current tab as img, when user **clicks on a link** in my extension , and open in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

- [Capturing tab as an image](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab)
- [Data URI format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)
- [Creating a new tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tabs.html#method-create)